# how to get child properties of the div object for rational functinal tester

Tags: rft

in my application i have a dropdown which is div object.the dropdown contain names and checkboxes.i need select the checkbox based on name. checkbox dont have any name.just index.can any one suggest how to get chaild items or properties of the objects for div object.

and the second question is i have tree view .which is teleric object.RFT is unable to find the object.it identifying as one all tree view is one object.its not identifying the childs,sub tree items....

so please help me on this two issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get the checkboxes as follows:

```
void  getCheckBoxes(TestObject parentDiv)
{
    TestObject[] checkboxes = parentDiv.find(atDescendant(".class","Html.INPUT.checkbox"));
             System.out.println("Found " + checkboxes.length);
    //Go through them  , and decide which one to select. 
    for(TestObject checkbox: checkboxes)
    {

       System.out.println("Checkbox Value: "+ checkbox.getProperty(".value"));
    }   

}
```

you can call the above method and pass it the parent DIV object.

About the second question:
You have not mentioed  how does RFT recognize the  one object for the tree ( means which proxy does it use  as per the  object map's  adminitrative properties for that object). 
Usually controls like tree /grid etc are recognized as one control and the items of these controls as  "Subitem" which are found by  specifying   subitem as  atPath("xyz->abc") etc.